# Correct use of Volley in an activity with Android Studio

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, android-volley, android-context

I've been thinking about the correct use of context cause I have a problem when I use `Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext());`

I don't know the correct context that I have to use, I've watched a tutorial and in the video the man use a `Fragment` but I am using an `Activity` so its diferent and also the same autor of the video wrote that we had to change the context if we want to use the same code in an `Activity`.

I've tried with:

- `getAplicationcontext()`
- `getContext()`
- `getBasedContext()`
- `getAplication()`

The worst it's that my aplication doesn´t tell the error, it said: `it has found the user: asd@gmalcom`, that means that aparently registration is succesfull but when I see the database there is nothing...

```
public class another extends AppCompatActivity implements 
Response.Listener<JSONObject>,Response.ErrorListener{

RequestQueue rq;
JsonRequest jrqt;
EditText txtnombre,txtapellido,txtcel,txtCorreo,txtContra,txtRecontraReg;
Button btnIngresar;
TextView txtCrear,txtolvido;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);
    txtnombre=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtxtnomReg);
    txtapellido=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtxtApellReg);
    txtcel=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtxtCelReg);
    txtContra=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtxtContraReg);
    txtCorreo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtxtCorreoReg);
    btnIngresar=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReg);
    txtCrear=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCrearCuenta);
    txtolvido=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtcontraOlvidadLog);
    //revisar esto
    **rq=Volley.newRequestQueue(getBaseContext());**

    btnIngresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            registrar_usuario();
        }
    });

}

private void registrar_usuario() {
    String urli="http://*************************************.php? 
            nombre_cli="+txtnombre.getText().toString()+
            "&apellido_cli="+txtContra.getText().toString()+
            "&correo_cli="+txtCorreo.getText().toString()+
            "&celular_cli="+txtcel.getText().toString()+
            "&contrasena_cli="+txtContra.getText().toString();
    jrqt=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,urli,null,this,this);
    rq.add(jrqt);
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"No se pudo registrar el usuario 
"+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    Clientes cli=new Clientes();
    Toast.makeText(this,"Se ha encontrado el 
usuario"+txtCorreo.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //limpiartextview();
}

private void limpiartextview() {
    txtnombre.setText("");
    txtapellido.setText("");
    txtCorreo.setText("");
    txtcel.setText("");
    txtContra.setText("");
}
}
```

Comment: Grammar corrections and capitalization

Comment: Most of the time I use `getApplicationContext()`.